# find all text contained in single quotes (characters, numbers, special characters)

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse this string:

> :p0 = 'R' [Type: String (0)], :p1 = 'Y'
>   [Type: String (0)], :p2 = 'HBP00' [Type: String (0)], :p3 = 'MAG.PF'

and I've come up with this expression which works quite well for me:

```
:p\d*\b\s=\s'\w{1,}'
```

Basically I am trying to match all the parameters and the values:

- :p0 = 'R'
- :p1 = 'Y'
- :p2 = 'HBP00'
- :p3 = 'MAG.PF'

but I've noticed the expression doesn't work on **:p3** cause of the dot, I reckon.
I don't seem to be able to find a way to get all the text contained in single quotes.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**

I've mixed some information I got here and the one which works for me seems to be:

```
:p\d*\s=\s'[^']+'
```

Comment: Also, the word boundary escape sequence (`\b`) is unnecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know c# regex syntax very well, but you should either

- include the "." character (something like `:p\d*\b\s=\s'[\w\.]+'`) or,
- accept any character excluded single quotes (something like
  `:p\d*\b\s=\s'[^']+'`)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this pattern:

```
'([\w.]+)'
```

Demo: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=89309902-4eac-4975-97bc-9c73640ee81f

Comment: Thanks for your help but, as I said to @srsbarro, this situation would be matched `:p4 = 'MAG/PF'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
:p\d*\b\s=\s'[\w\.]{1,}'
```

That will include the . character. If you need to expand the expression to include more characters try adding them between the brackets.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It works great but it doesn't match all the characters: This situation wouldn't be trapped `:p4 = 'MAG/PF'`. I don't know what's gonna be in that string. Could be pretty much any character.

Answer (score 1):

For the example above: `:p\d*\b\s=\s'[\w\.]{1,}'` should do the trick. Instead of looking for only word characters in between the single quotes, this looks for word characters & the "dot" character. If you need to search for additional special characters, you can add them to the square bracket section `[\w\.]` e.g. `[\w\.\?]` would search for word characters, the dot, and a question mark

example: http://regexr.com?2uf6v

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't know which characters I might add in the future cause it can be pretty much anything.